# Stopping C# language internationalization

Tags: c#, internationalization

I've got a C# .NET program here with the following line for loading strings:

```
m_resource_manager = new ResourceManager("Foo.FooStrings", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

as was recommended to me.  Right now, I've got a request to stop doing these translations, and do everything in English.  I want to make changes as low-impact and reversible as possible.

I'd like to change this line so it always loads the English string table, but I don't know what to specify, or for that matter whether this is a good way or not.

Is this a good way to stick to English?  If so, how should I write it?  If not, what should I do instead?

Comment: Just exclude the other language satellite assembly?

Comment: How about you refuse to do this? That’s what I would do. Why remove a perfectly good and working feature for no benefit? Why exclude speakers of other languages like that? It just makes no sense.

Comment: @Timwi:  Because the request came from the only non-English-speaking users.  This is strictly internal software, not distributed outside the company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify culture right before this string:

```
#if ENGLISH_ONLY
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
#endif
```

Then if you compile assembly with `ENGLISH_ONLY` symbol all loading strings will be in English.

Comment: Would this affect other things, or just the string translation?

Comment: It's affect all resources translation and different formatting of dates, currencies etc (when you call `DateTime.Now.ToString()` for example).

Comment: Can I reset `CurrentUICulture` and `CurrentCulture` back to what they were after executing the `new ResourceManager` line?

Answer (score 1):

can you not just remove all resx files but the default which can be in English?

Comment: I can, but my boss would rather leave everything in.

Comment: @David Thornley I think you are stuck with whyleee's suggestion, which is a good one by the way, I think you could also set this in the app or web.config too depending on whether in isa winforms or web aoo